# Filter variable by date

Tags: string, date, stata

I have a column in my data file in Stata for dates that looks like this:

```
1/29/2018 16:28:02
```

What is the syntax to filter by date?

For example, to find all observations where the date is `January 29, 2018`?

Something like `keep if data > ???`

The date is in red which I believe means string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following toy example:

```
clear

input str20 string_date
"1/14/2018 18:28:02"
"1/19/2018 16:12:13"
"1/26/2018 17:54:43"
"2/11/2018 20:34:25"
"3/29/2018 22:21:01"
end
```

You first need to convert the string variable to numeric:

```
generate double numeric_date = clock(string_date, "MDY hms")
format numeric_date %tc

list

     +-----------------------------------------+
     |        string_date         numeric_date |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. | 1/14/2018 18:28:02   14jan2018 18:28:02 |
  2. | 1/19/2018 16:12:13   19jan2018 16:12:13 |
  3. | 1/26/2018 17:54:43   26jan2018 17:54:43 |
  4. | 2/11/2018 20:34:25   11feb2018 20:34:25 |
  5. | 3/29/2018 22:21:01   29mar2018 22:21:01 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Then you must to find the unformatted value of interest:

```
display %15.0g numeric_date[4]
1834000465000

list if numeric_date == 1834000465000

     +-----------------------------------------+
     |        string_date         numeric_date |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  4. | 2/11/2018 20:34:25   11feb2018 20:34:25 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

or:

```
keep if numeric_date == 1834000465000
```

Type `help format` and `help datetime_display_formats` for more details on working with datetimes.